# How do I find the amount of memory used by a program?

Tags: memory, bluej

I'm running a couple of Java programs in BlueJ. I want to be able to know how much memory the program uses for a given input value. Is there any way I can do this?

Comment: Your question is probably unrelated to BlueJ. You could use some other IDE (or Java compiler). So I guess you need to remove the `bluej` tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) to get the maximum amount of memory that your Java application can use [Runtime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html):

```
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime(); 
System.out.println("max memory: " + runtime.maxMemory() / 1024);
```

2)to get how much memory that JVM has allocated for your application :

```
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime(); 
System.out.println("allocated memory: " + runtime.totalMemory() / 1024);
```

3)to get how much memory is being used by your application:

```
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime(); 
System.out.println("free memory: " + runtime.freeMemory() / 1024);
```

Comment: Nod bad for a first answer. For your future answers: format code appropriately (indenting it with four spaces), and perhaps link to relevant documentation

Answer (score 0):

It could be **[operating system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system) specific**; notably the [JVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine) manages Java allocated memory, but you might call external functions in C++ using [JNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface) which are allocating memory too (e.g. your Java program calling [OpenCV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCV) functions), and you could be interested in the [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space) of your current [process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing)). On Linux you might use [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) and read and parse `/proc/self/statm` or `/proc/self/stat`  or `/proc/self/status`. If your process has pid 1234, you could also try `cat /proc/1234/maps` ijn an other terminal, or use [pmap(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/pmap.1.html). On other operating systems, you'll need to dive into their appropriate documenation.

If you only care about the memory directly used by the JVM, use the [Runtime class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html) as [answered by Hans](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46861279/841108).

BTW, your JVM has a [garbage collector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_(computer_science)), and so defining what exactly is the amount of memory used is not trivial.